# SVCHOST Executed without any arguements

Tags: detection, windows-server, siem

Our SIEM has a Sigma rule that alerts when svchost is launched without any arguments.  The logs are from a domain controller which unfortunately I don't have access to to verify.  I will be reaching out to our system admin, but can anyone think of why a Windows domain controller would launch svchost without any arguments?  A link to the Sigma rule is below.

Rule: [Suspect Svchost Activity](https://github.com/SigmaHQ/sigma/blob/master/rules/windows/process_creation/proc_creation_win_svchost_execution_with_no_cli_flags.yml)

Comment: Might be worth running something like this just to see if a service image path matches/been changed:
`Get-ItemProperty hklm:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\* | % { if ($_.imagepath -match "svchost"){ write-host "$($_.pschildname), $($_.imagepath)"}}`
Looking at the rule, I don't think it should match this potential process: `C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\SMSvcHost.exe` as it might match selection1 but I think selection2 would be ok and you need both to be true.

Comment: I wonder if the process making the call can't get the command line. For example, as Admin, run `Get-WmiObject Win32_Process -Filter "name like '%svchost%'" | select processid, name, processname, description, commandline | Sort-Object commandline | ogv`.  This will list a number of svchost.exe processes without command lines, for me both of which are  ProtectionLevel: PsProtectedSignerWindows-Light.  If you use Process Explorer with a filter for svchost, and add the Protection column, it might highlight this.

Comment: Even running: `Get-WmiObject Win32_Process -Filter "name like '%svchost%'" | select * | Sort-Object commandline | ogv` as local system user, the columns `Path`, `CommandLine`, `ExecutablePath`, `MaximumWorkingSetSize`, `MinimumWorkingSetSize` are not obtainable for the Protection Level PsProtectedSignerWindows-Light. The process obtaining the information would have to call the necessary APIs with certain flags to get this information. https://docs.microsoft.com/windows/win32/procthread/process-security-and-access-rights

Comment: Of interest - https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20091125-00/?p=15923 and https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19685/Get-Process-Info-with-NtQueryInformationProcess

Comment: Thanks everyone! Got busy and just getting back to this.  I appears the rule needs to be tuned as other customers are reporting false positives.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it turned out to be a false positive